# Can not load RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I use this import statement in one of component file:

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private currentUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
}
```

When the browser loads the app, it throws the exception below:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/rxjs
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/components/app.js
at eval (native)
at SystemJSLoader.__exec (http://localhost:3000/vendors.js:3320:16)
```

I don't know why it didn't work. Cause Angular2 worked already.
Could any one please help me this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that it's not somethying related to concatenation with Gulp but with the module you use.

You should use one of the following:

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

or

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/subject/BehaviorSubject';
```

In fact, RxJS doesn't register a `rxjs` module directly but sub modules (something like `rxjs/something`). So SystemJS can't find a previously registered module so it tries to load from the address `http://localhost:3000/rxjs` but a 404 error is returned...

Comment: cool! Thanks Thierry. It works perfectly. But I don't know why many people mentioned the use of importing statement: import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs'; I made me waste a lot of time.

Comment: +1 to the last comment. A lot of examples are doing simply `import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';` How is that possible?